# Segmentation fault when accessing a 2D array in a structure whose pointer is returned from a function

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation

I made a structure who has two members (`int` and `int**`), and I return the pointer to this structure from one function to `main()`. It is fine to access the `int` value in the structure. However, in `main()` I got Segmentation fault : 11 when I tried to access the element of the 2D array.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct Square {
    int value;
    int **array;
} Square;

Square * generate();

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    Square *sqrptr = generate();

    printf("%d\n", sqrptr -> value);
    /* It prints 1 */

    /* Print out the 2D array */
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 3 ; j++){
            printf("%d ", *(*((sqrptr -> array) + i) + j));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    /* It gives segmentation fault */

    return 0;
}

Square * generate(){
    Square mySquare;
    mySquare.value = 1;
    mySquare.array = malloc(sizeof(int*) * 3);

    /* Initialize the 2D array */
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        *(mySquare.array + i) = malloc(sizeof(int) * 3);
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            *(*(mySquare.array + i) + j) = 0;
        }
    }

    /* Print out the 2D array */
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 3l ; j++){
            printf("%d ", *(*(mySquare.array + i) + j));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    /* I can see the complete 2D array here */

    Square *sqrptr = &mySquare;

    return sqrptr;    
}
```

I have tried to generate the `Square` in `main()`, and use one pointer of the structure to access my 2D array. It works fine, so I guess I have missed something when I use a pointer returned from other functions. On the other hand, I can access the `int value` successfully, so I have no clues now.

Could someone please explain the underlying reason for this segmentation fault? Thanks!

Comment: Square * generate(); does not make sense to my eyes

Comment: @SaeidYazdani I just declared the function before `main()`.

Comment: You return the address of a local variable. The variable does not exist anymore when the main function want to use it.

Comment: @SaeidYazdani As per latest C standard, that is __required__.

Comment: @mch I was thinking this too, but I can access `sqrptr -> size`, which makes it confusing to me.

Comment: BTW whoever who downvoted the question please leave a comment, so I can improve my questions in the future.

Comment: use malloc to allocate on heap then return it.

Comment: It is still undefined behaviour. One possibility of undefined behaviour is, that it looks like expected behaviour.

Comment: If you use `malloc` to allocate the storage on the heap, don't forget to `free` it when it is no longer required.

Comment: @mch Hmm, so if I want to make it on the heap, should I do `mySquare = malloc(sizeof(Square))`? It becomes more confusing now. I am so sorry.

Comment: @JayWong no, because you define `mySquare` as a `struct`, not a pointer, so that `struct` already has a local presence on the stack. Please see the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're returning a pointer to a local variable (`&mySquare`). Stack memory (where local variables reside) is when the function returns, so the resulting pointer is pointing to invalid memory. Allocate the struct, and return the pointer to heap memory:

```
Square *my_square = malloc(sizeof *my_square);
//do stuff
return my_square;
```

Or pass a pointer to a stack variable as argument:

```
Square * generate(Square *my_square)
{
    //in case pointer wasn't provided, allocate
    if (my_square == NULL) {
        my_square = malloc(sizeof *my_square);
        if (!my_square)
            return NULL; // or exit or whatever
    }
    //initialize members. To initialize array to 3x3 zero matrix, you can use:
    for (int i=0;i<3;++i)
        my_square.array[i] = calloc(3, sizeof *my_square->array[i]);
    //or even, if you change array member to type int*:
    my_square.array = calloc(3*3, sizeof *my_square->array);
    //at the end:
    return my_square;
}
```

The latter is arguably the most flexible solution: if you want to work on stack, you call the function like so:

```
Square my_stack_square;
generate(&my_stack_square);
```

If you need to use heap memory, you can use:

```
Square *my_heap_square = generate(NULL);
```

As Jonathan Leffler pointed out, for a small struct such as this, returning by value isn't too much of a cost. Getting a struct on heap can be achieved in the same way as returning any other type:

```
Square generate( void )
{
    Square my_square;
    //initialize
    return my_square;
}
//call like so:
Square sq = generate();
```

The idea here is that you'll use a local variable in the `generate` function to create a new square, initialize the fields, and then return it. Because in C everything is passed *by value*, this essentially means the function will assign the value of the local variable from the generate function to the caller's scoped `sq` variable. For small structs such as this, that's perfectly fine.

What's more, a common thing for compilers to do is to optimise these kinds of functions to the equivalent of the second example I posted: Essentially your function will be creating a new `Sqaure` object on the stack memory of the caller. This *can* happen, that's not to say it will. It depends on the optimization levels used when compiling, and on the size of the struct you're returning.

Basically, if you want to keep the code as close to what you have now, it's probably easiest to stick to the first version (returning a heap pointer).

The more flexible approach is the second one (as it allows you to use stack and heap, depending on how you call the function).

For now, using the third approach is perfectly fine: the compiler will most likely optimize the code to whatever makes most sense anyway.

Comment: `is when` -> `is lost when` ? `P` -> `{` ? Is it on purpose you want to return a `Square*` in example 2?

Comment: In example 2, not all control paths return a value.

Comment: Ups, I see now that it **is** on purpose that example 2 returns a pointer.

Comment: Or, for this small of a structure, consider `Square generate(void);` and then simply: `Square sqr = generate();` — it works fine for simple structures like this one.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct Square {
    int value;
    int **array;
} Square;

Square * generate();

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    Square *sqrptr = generate();

    printf("%d\n", sqrptr -> value);
    /* It prints 1 */

    /* Print out the 2D array */
    int i,j;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < 3 ; j++){
            printf("%d ", *(*((sqrptr -> array) + i) + j));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    /* It gives segmentation fault */

    return 0;
}

Square * generate(){
    Square* mySquare = (Square*) malloc(sizeof(Square)); //c++ compiler
    //Square* mySquare = (void*) malloc(sizeof(Square)); //c compiler
    mySquare->value = 1;
    mySquare->array = malloc(sizeof(int*) * 3);

    /* Initialize the 2D array */
    int i,j;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        *(mySquare->array + i) = malloc(sizeof(int) * 3);
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            *(*(mySquare->array + i) + j) = 0;
        }
    }

    /* Print out the 2D array */
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < 3l ; j++){
            printf("%d ", *(*(mySquare->array + i) + j));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    /* I can see the complete 2D array here */
    return mySquare;
}
```

Comment: Don't cast the return of `malloc` & co in C

Comment: I compiled with g++, but yea it should be `(void*) ` with c compiler

Comment: There should have been NO CAST at all. Casting pointers in C is [considered harmful](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/1230836)

Comment: It works now, thank you so much! Could you please expand `Square* mySquare = (void*) malloc(sizeof(Square));` this part a little bit for me? It looks new to me.

Comment: @JayWong `malloc` already redurns a `void *`, there's no reason to cast it. In fact, in C, casting the return of `malloc` & co is considered bad practice. The idiomatic way to allocate memory in C is: `my_ptr = malloc(n * sizeof *my_ptr);` where `n` is the number of elements you need to store in memory. hard-coding `sizeof(type_name)` is arguably more error-prone than inferring the size of the type you allocate from the variable you assign the pointer to: `int *x; x = malloc(3 * sizeof *x);` will allocate memory to store 3 `int`'s. change the declaration to `long *x` and `malloc` will work

Comment: If you have a number of hard-coded `sizeof(int)` in `malloc` and `realloc` calls, you'll have to change all of those. If you use `sizeof *ptr_var`, you only ever need to change the variable declaration

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Yes I see what you mean now. I will practice using `my_ptr = malloc(n * sizeof *my_ptr)` now. One unrelated question, using underscore(`my_square`) or capital letter(`mySquare`) in variable name is more idiomatic in C? I like using underscore, but I see a lot of people using capital letter.

Comment: @JayWong: for the most part, camelCase or snake_case depends on personal preference. In my experience, the use of underscores is more prevalent in C, though. The important thing is to choose a style you like best, and be consistent